# How to avoid generating the same random String twice in a row in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, random

I‘m trying to get a random value from an array of strings from an SQLite database, without getting the same value twice in a row (same value should be able to appear again later, but not immediately after). How can I achieve this in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only care about not repeating the value as the *next* value, just remember the previous value and reject the next value if it is the same as the previous value.

Here's a playground example. First, we try this the simplest way:

```
let pep = ["manny", "moe", "jack"]

func fetchRandomPep() -> String {
    return pep.randomElement()!
}

for _ in 1...100 {
    let result = fetchRandomPep()
    print(result)
}
```

Well, you probably got many repeated results. Let's prevent that by writing our loop in a different way:

```
var prev = ""
for _ in 1...100 {
    var result = fetchRandomPep()
    while result == prev {
        result = fetchRandomPep()
    }
    prev = result
    print(result)
}
```

Now there are no repetitions!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your criteria for when the same value able to appear again

you can try using the `shuffle` or `shuffled` function to shuffle your array and you can get the value from first to last to make it never show the same value

```
let x = [1, 2, 3].shuffled()
// x == [2, 3, 1]

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numbers.shuffle()
// numbers == [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a randomIndex method to return a random index except a previous index that you can store in a var. So the first time you pass nil it will return any index of a collection. If you pass the last random index just remove it from the collection indices, return a new random index and use it to call your method the next time you need a random index:

Something like:

```
extension RandomAccessCollection where Index == Int {
    func randomIndex(except index: Index? = nil) -> Index? {
        guard let index = index else { return indices.randomElement() }
        var indices = Array(self.indices)
        indices.remove(at: index)
        return indices.randomElement()
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let strings = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"]
    lazy var index = strings.randomIndex()! // this will return any index of the collection to start
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    var randomElement: String {
        // this will get the next random index after returning the random element
        defer { index = strings.randomIndex(except: index)! }
        return strings[index]
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.randomElement  // "Two"
vc.randomElement  // "Three"
vc.randomElement  // "Two"
vc.randomElement  // "Eight"
vc.randomElement  // "Nine"
vc.randomElement  // "Six"
vc.randomElement  // "One"
vc.randomElement  // "Four"
vc.randomElement  // "Six"
vc.randomElement  // "Five"
vc.randomElement  // "Eight"
vc.randomElement  // "Five"
vc.randomElement  // "Four"
vc.randomElement  // "Seven"
vc.randomElement  // "Four"
```